# FATAL: No bootable medium found

Tags: assembly, operating-system, boot, iso, bootloader

I have small problem. I have made very simple bootloader. After it's creation I created new empty .iso file.

```
mkisofs -o cd.iso content
```

Then I used Okteta editor and I filled first 512 bytes with bootloader.
[image: Okteta]

Then I started .iso image in Virtual Box. 
My problem is error message:

```
FATAL: No bootable medium found
```

Does anybody know how can I make it working? Where have I error?
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just copy your floppy/HDD boot sector onto a cd image and expect it to work. To make a bootable cd-rom, you need to abide by the [El Torito](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_%28CD-ROM_standard%29) standard. [Here's](http://paulski.com/zpages.php?id=1814) a quick guide how to make a bootable cd from a floppy image.

Comment: So Iþve created empty .img file with dd. Now I have .bin bootloader. How can I put it to .img?

Comment: How you make a floppy img from boot sector? If you only have a boot sector, that in itself is a floppy image.

Comment: I've created empty DD and I pasted bootloader (again Okteta hex editor).

Comment: Then you should have a floppy image that you can use with mkisofs. Looks like you got some help in your other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824231/no-bootloader-found-on-bootable-medium

Comment: Still not working but it should... I can't do anything with it. I accept 'cause you told me how.